# What should I use to establish a threshold to detect threshold crossings?

Tags: standard-deviation, signal-processing, threshold, signal-detection, mad

I have data graphed in green here:

[image: data graph]

I want to detect the peaks but I don't know how to define the threshold values. The blue lines are mean ± standard deviation. Using that, I would miss the three peaks towards the right.

I looked at median ± MAD, but that was down in the noise.

I'd like the threshold to be more like the red lines (which weren't calculated–I just drew them in). What's a good way to define a threshold that is "a little above or below where most of the values are"?

Comment: If your signal is typically as clean as that then consider yourself lucky. Typically, these problems aren't solved using standard deviation or MAD. Probably the most common way to detect peaks is to apply a smoothing filter then calculate the derivative at each point using a windowed set of points. You can identify the peaks by seeing when the derivative direction changes. If your signal is always as clean as your picture shows then you can probably skip the smoothing part and simply only accept peak points that exceed a threshold. Do some research on Digital Signal Processing.

Comment: Usually you'd identify the thresholds based on testing. I would think it is far more accurate that way as you can manually identify what you want to call a peak or not and can identify how often you are misclassifying peaks. If you have to calculate dynamically then I still don't see where STD or MAD comes into play unless all the peaks are supposed to have the same height. But even then, you'd probably have to throw away outliers (high peaks) that exceed some manually determined threshold or your results will be skewed.